# Query Feature license usage

Tags: api, licenses

In few docs I see suggestion to query the user's last login data to check if user is actively using the license or not, is there any way we can get to know if the feature license is being used properly through API or the suggested approach we can use to determine for feature license usage as well?

Comment: What do you mean by *being used properly* ?

Comment: please do not post duplicate questions

Comment: @Badbaxx I want to check If the user is using the assigned license or not.

Comment: @DavidCheng that query was related to license information. This query is regarding the feature license usage, for example if an user is assigned Chatter Answer feature license so I want to check whether he is using that license or not